# Verify Signature with public key P265r1

Tags: flutter, dart, cryptography, ecdsa

I would like to verify a signature with a public key and can't find any way to do this in dart. In Swift, there is an easy solution via the `SecKeyVerifySignature` function. Is there something similar in flutter? I could only find the cryptography library but that won't let me set my own public key. Is there any way to archive this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pointycastle` package. `ECDSASigner` is initialized with an `ECPublicKey`..

```
  final verifier = ECDSASigner(SHA256Digest())
    ..init(
      false, // verify vs sign
      PublicKeyParameter(key), // key is an ECPublicKey
    );
  verifier.verifySignature(message, signature);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have extracted my public key from a certificate via the ASN1Parser. So it is saved in a List<int>. Is there a way to convert that list to an ECPublicKey?

Comment: Check out the `basic_utils` package and its method: `ECPublicKey ecPublicKeyFromDerBytes(Uint8List bytes);`

Comment: It'll do the ASN.1 bits for you too, I think - check the `fromPem()` versions

Comment: Did that help??

Comment: Some, there is a function called ```CryptoUtils.ecPublicKeyFromPem(String pem)```but it gives me the Error: ```_CastError (type 'ASN1Integer' is not a subtype of type 'ASN1ObjectIdentifier' in type cast)```

Comment: It seems like the problem is the curve ```1.2.840.10045.4.3.2 ecdsaWithSHA256 (ANSI X9.62 ECDSA algorithm with SHA256)```. It isn't included in the package. Is there a way to implement that?

Comment: Are you able to update the question with the certificate PEM?